# Utc two hours behind

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin.android, utc

I am trying to extract the creation time of a video using `System.IO.File.GetCreationTimeUtc(file)`but the time I am getting is two hours behind, I should be getting 11:17 and I get back 09:17. The same goes when I try to use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`or `DateTime.UtcNow` to get the current time. Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: if `DateTime.UtcNow` is returning a time that is two hours off, your computer's timezone might be set wrong, or maybe you don't understand UTC time?  It's hard to say without additional detail.

Comment: What time zone is configured on the device?

Comment: How can I figure out if my timezone is wrong on a mac? I have already looked into Date & Time preferences and set the Region to the right country

Comment: Am I right that you running that on android emulator on Mac? You will need to check locale on emulated Android then

Comment: Yes, I am using Genymotion and the time was wrong. I changed it and now I get the right current time but the creation time of my video is still 2 hours off.

Comment: did you create this video after you fixed timezone? Was it created on this android device?

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting time in UTC TimeZone ([Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) while you see time in your system in a local timezone (and file creation time is shown in local timezone as well).

You can simply call `File.GetCreationTime` to get expected time, which will be in your location timezone

Comment: Now it is 6 hours behind

Comment: What is used as a reference? As I understand you compare time on your Mac and emulated device so you need to make sure you have the same locale on both these devices (Mac and emulated android)